# Same socket read and write done by 2 different threads with EPOLL Handler per each thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, epoll

There are many questions that are related to this. But I couldn't find a question that match my scenario.
Basically my setup is something like below [Linux],
A non-blocking Linux TCP socket is created and handed over to 2 threads (one reader and other writer). Each thread has it's own EPOLL handler(created with [epoll_create1](https://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_create1)). At each thread, when socket is shared
(1) Reader Thread : socket(FD) is immediately added to epoll handler([epoll_ctl](https://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_ctl)) with event EPOLLIN.
(2) Writer thread : [write](https://linux.die.net/man/3/write)s done to the socket(FD). If write returns a lesser written count
than intended(i.e. TCP buffered condition), then FD is added to Epoll handler(of writer thread) with event EPOLLOUT and writing paused until [epoll_wait](https://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_wait) returns socket is writable(after that FD is removed from this epoll handler)
My questions are,

1. Do you see any caveats in this approach ?
2. If the socket is closed by the remote end, Reader Thread can detect it(in most cases) since it is in Epoll handler(and epoll_wait called continuously). BUT, How can Writer thread detect the remote end closure before it is detected by write failure(e.g. in a case where writes done with large time gaps) ? If I were to add it EPoll handler only to detect the disconnection, what should I use for epoll_event::events (e.g. EPOLLRDHUP and/or EPOLLHUP or any other) ?